# Do Mormons consider participating in game shows to be gambling?

Tags: lds, gambling

The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints (Mormons) are opposed to gambling. [From their official website](https://www.lds.org/topics/gambling?lang=eng):

> The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints is opposed to gambling, including lotteries sponsored by governments. Church leaders have encouraged Church members to join with others in opposing the legalization and government sponsorship of any form of gambling.
>
> Gambling is motivated by a desire to get something for nothing. This desire is spiritually destructive. It leads participants away from the Savior's teachings of love and service and toward the selfishness of the adversary. It undermines the virtues of work and thrift and the desire to give honest effort in all we do.

[This answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/16723/16688) also states that the LDS Church will not accept monetary donations earned from gambling (although unfortunately that part is unsourced).

Is participating in a game show considered gambling? Does it matter if it is a trivia show, like *[Jeopardy!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeopardy!)*, or one with a great deal of random chance, like *[Deal or No Deal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deal_or_No_Deal)*?

This question is inspired by [Ken Jennings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Jennings), who had a 75 game winning streak on *Jeopardy!* in 2004, and professes to be Mormon.

*Related: [What is the baptist view on "gambling" in scenarios like "Jeopardy!"?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/18858/16688)*

Comment: Do you have to put money into *Jeopardy* or *Deal or No Deal* to play it? Anyways, this question is harder to answer than it may seem. Is playing the stock market gambling? What about buying a house? Where is the line drawn? That, I think, is a better question, but I'll forewarn it is difficult to answer, and I am not sure there is an official statement on it.

Comment: @Matt I’m just interested in game shows, but feel free to ask a new question about if Mormons consider the stock market to be gambling, if you like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

First I'll refer you to the [Law SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/5854/what-are-the-legalities-of-game-shows) which mentions that game shows are not gambling. Because technically game shows aren't gambling there doesn't seem to have been any doctrine from the LDS church on game shows.

In [D&C 58:26](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/58.26#p25) it says:

> 26 For behold, **it is not meet that I should command in all things**; for he that is compelled in all things, the same is a slothful and not a wise servant; wherefore he receiveth no reward.

Some LDS members may believe stronger beliefs on game shows, raffles, stock market, or house buying but there is no right answer for everyone. Each member and family can receive personal revelation for

> our specific personal needs, responsibilities, and questions and to help us strengthen our testimony.<sup>2</sup>

Several Mormons have participated in game shows besides Ken Jennings including

- Donny Osmond, who hosted Pyramid
- Ray Combs, who hosted Family Feud
- Al Harrington, who appeared on To Tell the Truth
- Daniel LeFevre, who won six figures on Millionaire<sup>1</sup>

<sub>1 http://www.ldsliving.com/Mormons-on-Game-Shows-5-Fun-Facts/s/79637?page=1#story-content</sub>

<sub>2 https://www.lds.org/topics/revelation?lang=eng</sub>